# Flutter - how I can detect "changed country" in my app?

Tags: flutter, dart, background, geolocation

This is my user case: when a user moves from one country to another country - need to show a message in my app(android and iOS).

At the moment I found one solution: periodically detect the location of the user and check whether the country has changed.

but this solution has several disadvantages:

1. background mode in iOS working as "black box". there is no guarantee when this will work.
2. The application must be in the background, otherwise it will not work.

Maybe there are other options? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Flutter has very limited support for running code while the application in the background, but yes it is possible, see an example here https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124